# Unable to start the FrameGrabber

Tags: java

I am using Netbeans IDE and this error occurred when I tried to run the project:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start the FrameGrabber
    at org.imesha.examples.javacv.JavaCVExample.start(JavaCVExample.java:75)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

If you need to see code from JavaCVExample.java or pom.xml, please tell me and I will edit this post. What could be the possible solution to this?

EDIT(updated):

Code around line 75 from JavaCVExample.java:

```
 public void start() {
      frameGrabber = new 
      FFmpegFrameGrabber("USB\\VID_090C&PID_71B3&MI_00\\6&9D4DD26&1&0000");
      frameGrabber.setFormat("DirectShow");
      frameGrabber.setImageWidth(640);
      frameGrabber.setImageHeight(480);

        logger.debug("Starting frame grabber");
        try {
            frameGrabber.start();
            logger.debug("Started frame grabber with image width-height : {}-{}", frameGrabber.getImageWidth(), frameGrabber.getImageHeight());
        } catch (FrameGrabber.Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error when initializing the frame grabber", e);
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to start the FrameGrabber", e);
        }

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            window.setVisible(true);
        });

        process();

        logger.debug("Stopped frame grabbing.");
    }
```

Comment: The Exception is thrown in ``JavaCVExample.start``. We cannot guess what's happening there...

Comment: Please show the code (use [Edit]) from `JavaCVExample.java` file around line # **75** and identify this particular line.

Comment: I don't know if you get notifications when I edit this post, so I decided to let you know that it is edited now by commenting here.

Comment: We'll need a lot more context. What is frameGrabber? Where is it initialized?